# Unexpected join() results in peewee

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I am making a clone of twitter using Python Flask just for fun. So, I have these three models **User**(name, username, email,...), **Relationship**(follower, followee) and **Tweet**(user, content). I want to filter out the tweets of the users I am following by performing the following query.

```
Tweet.select().join(
         Relationship, on=Relationship.followee
        ).where(Relationship.follower==current_user)
```

This query runs with no error except it gives unexpected results. It filters out my own(logged in user's) Tweets instead of the tweets of the users I am following. I searched a bit and found out that we can achieve the desired thing but with a different query:

```
Tweet.select().where(Tweet.user << current_user.get_followees())
```

where **get_followees** is a function defined in the User model class that returns users I am following. I am happy that I got the results I expected but I want to know what was wrong/missing in my first query. BTW I am using **sqlite**.

Comment: The generated query logs as `('SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."username", "t1"."name", "t1"."email" FROM "user" AS t1 WHERE ("t1"."username" = ?) LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0', [u'username'])`. Note the complete lack of a join ...

Comment: Which query are you talking about? The first one or the last one.

Comment: The first one. And I am confused that there's no join at all ...